# Como cargar multiples archivos XML a MySQL

Tags: php, java, mysql, xml

necesito de su orientación para lo siguiente :
En mi servidor web tengo un directorio donde se guardan facturas en formato XML, se genera un archivo por cada factura emitida por lo que solamente conozco la extension del archivo. La información de cada XML necesito almacenarla en una BD MySQL, hasta ahora solo he encontrado la manera de hacerlo con un solo archivo y conociendo el nombre y extension. Podrían por favor orientarme sobre alguna función en PHP que me pueda ser util. De antemano agradezco su ayuda y les pido una disculpa si no es la manera correcta de solicitar ayuda, soy novato en esto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar la funcion scandir (http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), te daria todos los archivos de un directorio y usarias lo que ya tienes conociendo el nombre del archivo